VSCode mouse middle button deletes the selected text if any
Issue

Have some text selected/highlighted, then press the middle button on a mouse (/TrackPoint. I confirmed this issue occurs with both a mouse and a TrackPoint). By "middle" button, I mean the button or the wheel that lets you scroll on an operating system level.
The selected text gets deleted. 

Environment

I've been aware of this issue only on VSCode so far. E.g. on GMail editor this behavior is not seen.
Ubuntu 22.04

Related but different issues

askubuntu.com#4507 is discussing disabling the "paste" feature. I've disabled it by applying the solution in https://askubuntu.com/a/1144039/24203
stackoverflow.com#55394404 is discussing about enabling scrolling by middle button on VSCode. Without doing anything particular, I am already achieving that.

Things that are tried but no effect

Changing some Gnome (i.e. OS-level) settings are false already.
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse middle-click-emulation
false
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation
false
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.trackball middle-click-emulation
false




It may help in your search to call it the "middle button" which is a standard term.

@nullability Thx I updated my post to use "middle button".

Have you tried setting org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse middle-click-emulation,
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad middle-click-emulation and
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.trackball middle-click-emulation to false ? (using gsettings) if you have gnome. I don't have the same behavior as you. For my it's a simple paste

@Mike Thanks. As you see in the updated OP, those are already false.
